# partial static and dynamic $lookup

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "inventory",
      "as": "result",
      "let": {"_id": "$_id"},
      "pipeline": [ 
         { $match: 
           { $expr: 
             { 
               $and: [ { $eq: ["$adder_id", some_object_id] }, { $eq:  [ "$friend_id",  "$$_id" ] } ] 
             }  
           } 
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

In this `$lookup`, there are two $match conditions. The first is static, while the second is dynamic.

Would mongodb's query planner be able to optimize and run the static match condition once to find the superset of matching documents, cached it, and then from this superset run the second match condition for each document? And, bonus, is it able to use the index for the second conditon?

Comment: `ObjectId()` returns a random value, thus it will never match any value of `_id`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [static $lookup vs dynamic $lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76320325/static-lookup-vs-dynamic-lookup)

Comment: Sorry for the error. I changed my example.

Answer (score 0):

I would use it like this:

```
db.orders.aggregate([
   {
      "$lookup": {
         "from": "inventory",
         "as": "result",
         "let": { "_id": "$_id" },
         "pipeline": [
            { $match: { adder_id: some_object_id } },
            { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$friend_id", "$$_id"] } } }
         ]
      }
   }
])
```

Comment: I tried that as well. I am not sure it actually works. I was told that mongo will simply merge the two `$match`.  Do you have any documentation that suggests this might work as desired?

Comment: Have a look at the docs, it was already provided to you.

Comment: `it was already provided to you`. I am not sure what you mean by that. I don't see any links to the docs. Or do you mean that it's the general docs on the webste?

Comment: either way, I just tested. It doesn't work. It is just as slow.

Comment: Read your earlier questions. It is always the same: Provide sample input data, what are your indexes?

Comment: I have provided an answer based on your answer that seems to actually work. Can you take a look and comment on what you think?

Answer (score 0):

```
db.orders.aggregate([
   {
      "$lookup": {
         "from": "inventory",
         "as": "result",
         "let": { "id": "$_id" },
         "pipeline": [
            { $match: { adder_id: some_object_id } },
            { $set: { keep: { $cond: [ { $eq: ["$friend_id", "$$id"] }, true, false ] } } },
            { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$keep", true] } } }
         ]
      }
   }
])
```

Based on manual testing, this actually appears to have the desired effect. The query time is now significantly faster.

But of course, I don't think the second `$match` is using the index. Or will it. Can someone confirm?

Comment: Can you post the verbose (`"allPlansExecution"`) explain plans? And how many documents match the `adder_id` condition? Finally what are the indexes on the collections? You're correct that indexes aren't used after the initial data retrieval.

Comment: That's the same what I wrote in my answer. Apart from variable name `id` versus `_id` I don't see any difference. A generated field never uses an index.

Comment: In my lookup, I have an extra `$set` stage. Without this stage the query time is 24 seconds. With  it, query time is reduced to 8 seconds.